# Youtube IFrame API Cannot Cue Specific Playlists; no Error?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I've been using the YouTube IFrame API to shuffle multiple of my playlists together. I've got a very bare-bones HTML page with a 'next' and 'previous' button, and a bunch of javascript that loads up and plays videos and handles the button events.

The general order of events when the script loads is

```
* Wait for page load
* Wait for iframe API to load
* Create player
* For each playlist in [my playlists]
    * Cue Playlist
    * Wait for event CUED
    * Add all loaded videos to list of all videos
* Shuffle list of all videos
* Play the videos
```

This page worked just fine for all the playlists I regularly play until today. Suddenly, when loading specific playlists, I am no longer getting a `CUED` event (or any event, for that matter), it just hangs, waiting for the playlist to be cued; however, I can press the 'play' button on the iframe and play the first video in the playlist. Additionally, I don't get any events triggering the `onError` handler from the player; as far as I can tell, I get no feedback after calling `cuePlaylist`

The playlists in question are all personal playlists that are publicly available under my user.

Here's an example of a playlist that exhibits this behavior:

- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuh_GoPmqJB7ADc9_T0HtCQ1oQ3_rutjx

And here's an example of a playlist that does not; if I try to load this one, it works as expected (and as it did with the other playlist just yesterday):

- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuh_GoPmqJB7wclmbu-qicy5uLwnsTSHO

I wonder if maybe the issue is related to the content of the playlist; like it fails if one of the videos isn't allowed to be played in my country or something. But previously when that was the case, it would load just fine and then skip those videos during playback. I don't think the issue is related to the length of the playlist, because the working playlist example is significantly longer than the non-working one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to have resolved itself. I suspect it was a bug in the iframe api or maybe the youtube backend which has been fixed by the youtube engineers. So iframe team, if you see this, thanks!